# Facebook app review -

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

We understand that for Facebook to review apps, the app needs full functionality to be able to demonstrate the permissions needed through App Review.

In our case, we haven't started developing the app yet. Is there a way to contact the review team, explain our intended usage for the specific permission, know in advance that the app will pass, so that we can start programming knowing that when we will post for review, the app wont get rejected.

This could save a lot of time because If the App wont get accepted, the whole project can't continue.

Comment: No, that is not possible. I would suggest that you join the FB Developers Group (https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/), and explain what you want to do there - people there will at least be able to tell you if it is like it won’t fly at all, because it won’t be compliant with Platform Policy, or stuff like that. But there is no guarantee.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it focuses on support for a commercial product rather than a programming question. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rely on Facebook to give you an answer on your intended application flow and use of permissions (without Facebook being able to test and verify), you should consult the [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) and [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) documentation to see whether your idea or application is:

1. Allowed
2. Doesn't contravene any policy from Facebook
3. Uses the Facebook Platform & Permissions in the best possible way

If you app doesn't follow the policy and permission guidelines, you can be sure that Facebook will reject your app and won't grant you the required permissions. The documentation on Permissions is in particular useful to see where / when you are allowed to request such permission, and how it should be used.

If you can't justify why you need a particular permission, you won't get access to it.

Facebook will still need to use the application and see how it works before permissions are granted.

[Some additional tips on passing the review process can be found on my blog](https://www.webniraj.com/2016/05/17/facebook-api-getting-your-additional-permissions-approved/).